# Deleting Nodes and changing the head

Tags: c++11, linked-list, nodes

Okay so I'm working on a function that deletes a node that has the same name as the read in input. If it is a match that node must not be added to the new sequence.
So heres what I've got till now, my previous pointer is null at the end of the code i have no idea why

```
void deleteRecord (ifstream &batchfile, node *&h)
{
ofstream logfile;
logfile.open("freeplay.log", ios::app);
node *ptr = h;
node *previous = nullptr;
string term;
batchfile.seekg(1L, ios::cur);
getline(batchfile, term);
while (ptr)
{
    if (!strstr(ptr -> name.c_str(), term.c_str()))
    {
        previous = ptr;
    }
    previous = previous -> next;
    ptr = ptr -> next;
}
```

}

Comment: Is previous ptr the head of new list? Previous is going null because technically previous is behaving like ptr only. When ptr goes next, previous also goes next and so it will finally be null when ptr will be null.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. when I comment out the line "previous = previous -> next" it only stores the last node in it which is understandable because precious is not changing. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Did it work ? Why were you using the previous ptr?

Comment: nope... It didn't work

Comment: Obviously, but in this case when you are not commenting, previous will be null after this loop So either the if works or not, it will forward to next. I think you should write your previous = previous->next in if condition.

Comment: Okay so when I put it in the if loop, it is still null.

Comment: Is your if even getting executed for once?

Comment: Yup I have five values my if compares term with. One value is the same. So if should go through four times. Which i checked it is

Comment: What is previous used for?

Comment: Previous is basically a node pointer that stores all the nodes that is not the node that matched with the input.

Comment: So previous is also a list of all the nodes?

Comment: Check my answer and tell if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (ptr)
{
    if (!strstr(ptr -> name.c_str(), term.c_str()))
    {
        if(previous = nullptr){
            previous = ptr;
            head_previous = previous;
        } else {
            previous->next = ptr;
            previous = previous -> next;
            previous->next = null;
        }
    }

    ptr = ptr -> next;
}
```

Here I have assigned `previous to ptr` whenever if is executed. For the first time, `previous is same as ptr.` From next on I am linking `previous -> next to ptr.` 
Now after the loop, you can print the entire list of stored nodes whose head is `previous_head`;

Comment: Okay so I used your method right, and started printing form head_previous so all my node would be shown.
Here's what happened: the third data is the one that matches the input. So what it did was, it stored only the first two input in the list and stopped there. .. It's weird